# Steam Deck Japanese Full-Width Input In-Game

Tags: linux, input-languages, steam, japanese, steam-os

My issue is that I cannot input full-width Japanese hiragana or katakana in my Japanese steam game on Steam Deck (stable OS, 3.4.8). When I use the Japanese keyboard for the game currently, the error message displayed says (paraphrased) "please use full-width hiragana/katakana keyboard for input". The game will not start without the full-width keyboard and several other check points of the game require typing in this way as well.

Things I've tried:

1. credit here: https://gist.github.com/XargonWan/cc660daf92c224b7241cbf5a2bf12c47

japanese_locale_enabler.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo steamos-readonly disable
sudo pacman-key --init
sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux
sudo pacman -S glibc
sudo sed -i "s%#ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8%ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8%" /etc/locale.gen
sudo locale-gen
sudo steamos-readonly enable
Creator wrote this as well: echo "Done! Be sure to put LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 %command% in the game's startup options on Steam to enable the locale."
```

I ran this script in Konsole and tried LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 %command% in the startup options and the keyboard was not fixed.

2. Installing Fcitx 5 and Mozc for Fcitx 5 on the Steam Deck. Credit to this (these) user(s) here: https://steamcommunity.com/app/1675200/discussions/0/3838802451905782378/

Random combinations on my own time. Nothing has worked and it's very confusing as fix #1 worked as of early July 2023.

I am hoping to be able to input full-width Japanese hiragana and katakana on my game using the internal touchscreen keyboard...I know many others also have this same issue.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated and would service the global Steam Deck community.

Comment: Does Steamdeck run Windows, or some Linux flavor or Android?

Comment: @music2myear it's based on Arch Linux.

Comment: Have you reported this issue to Valve?

Comment: I have reported this to valve, yes.